# return back the value of g:textfield

Tags: grails

how can i show back the g:textfield value if the value already havebeen taken.

example :

```
<input type="text" name="simbol" id="simbol" value="${simbol}"/>
```

when input the textfield with "1A" then SAVE to database, then i input again with type "1A" again. it will be error because i protect with unique : true, when eror it will be return the input page..
and filled by "1A"

how can i do to get the "1A" when save error and return to the page?

```
catch(Exception E)
        {
            [simbol: params.simbol?: "",nama : params.nama?:""]
            flash.message = "Simbol Sudah Dipakai !!!   "
            redirect (action:"tambah")

        }
```

i use try cacth to throw unique save error. 
and 
[simbol: params.simbol?: "",nama : params.nama?:""], this line i tried to throw/get back the value when save eror or unique

Comment: You should send your parameter like this.
`redirect(action: 'tambah',params: [simbol: params.simbol?: "",nama : params.nama?:""])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need put back data into `model` and `render page.

In your code you redirect without params at all.

This is the common way to do that you need. (Controller code)

```
def unInstance = new Un(params)
  if (!unInstance.save(flush: true)) {
      render(view: "create", model: [unInstance: unInstance])
      return
    }
 ....
}
```

Comment: i mean when save erorr, it will be return to the page with the textfield filled by "1A"

Comment: you first need to pass your object in return then use in gsp page  <g:textField text='simbol' value='${simbol}' />

Comment: gsp code:<g:textField name="name" value="${unInstance?.name}"/>